# smartGWT add record into listGrid

Tags: java, smartgwt

I have client, server and somewhere in the middle my own defined datasource.

on the client, I have form, which values I want to add to, as a record into my listGrid, which is displayed right below. Anyone can give my a hint?

What I did so far, was, I sent the values from the form as a object to the server. It saved the object into file. When I wanted to display the newly entered object I had to fetch again.. I don´t want that.

Comment: Do you have the newly entered object on client side?

Answer (score 1):

If your datasource extends any implementation of `com.smartgwt.client.data.DataSource` then don't use form to send data but use `com.smartgwt.client.data.DataSource.addRecord(Record)` method. It'll cause client-server communication and all the magic will be performed by SmartGWT.

If your datasource does not extend `com.smartgwt.client.data.DataSource` then use `ListGrid.addData(Record)` just after you'll receive confirmation from the server side that data was successfully stored.

Comment: Hello, it does extend implementation of DataSource, how can i wrap values from a form fields to the record? In my implementation I have list<Student> stored in dataSource. So I bind the form on the client side: form.setDataSource(StudentDS.getInstance) I have done it for listGrid also. So now I want somehow add  Record to the ListGrid which is stored in my dataSource(StudentDS)